# ES6 if in arrow function

Tags: ecmascript-6

why does

```
$(input).on('keypress', e=> if (e.which == 13) $(btn).trigger('click'));
```

does not work ? I get  SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

`$(input).on('keypress', e=> { if (e.which == 13) $(btn).trigger('click'); });` works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first syntax

```
$(input).on('keypress', e=> if (e.which == 13) $(btn).trigger('click'));
```

is equivalent to

```
$(input).on('keypress', function (e) {
    return if (e.which == 13) $(btn).trigger('click')
    ^^^^^^
});
```

As this is not valid syntax, an error will be thrown.

While, the second code syntax

```
$(input).on('keypress', e => {
    if (e.which == 13) $(btn).trigger('click');
});
```

is correct and thus it works.

I'll suggest not to use Arrow function syntax when the function body contains more than one statements.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the logical and as a shorthand for the if condition

```
$(input).on('keypress', e => (e.which == 13) && $(btn).trigger('click'));
```

Comment: Notice that `return`ing `false` from a jQuery event handler has special semantics. I don't think they'd be appreciated here.